# MySQL | Subtract COUNT from SUM with different WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql

Here is an example table:

```
quizzes

id    user_id    quiz_id    has_passed    attempts
1     101        201        0             5          
2     101        202        1             1
3     102        201        1             3
4     103        203        1             2
```

I have two queries that I would like to combine to get the number of failed quiz attempts.

The first query gets the sum of all attempts for each quiz:

```
SELECT quiz_id, SUM(attempts) as sum
FROM quizzes
GROUP BY quiz_id
```

The second query gets counts the number of times a quiz has been passed:

```
SELECT quiz_id, COUNT(*) as count
FROM quizzes
WHERE has_passed =1
GROUP BY quiz_id
```

I want to subtract the number of passed attempts from the total attempts to get the number of failed attempts grouped by quiz_id.

What query would give me an output that would look something like this?

```
quiz_id    failed_attempts    
201        7
202        0
203        1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT quiz_id, SUM(attempts - has_passed) failed_attempts
FROM quizzes
GROUP BY quiz_id
```

Output

```
| QUIZ_ID | FAILED_ATTEMPTS |
-----------------------------
|     201 |               7 |
|     202 |               0 |
|     203 |               1 |
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ca565/2)**

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
SELECT quiz_id,
       SUM(attempts) - COUNT(CASE WHEN has_passed = 1 THEN 1 END)
         AS failed_attempts
  FROM quizzes
 GROUP
    BY quiz_id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
SELECT quiz_id, SUM(attempts) AS attempts, SUM(attempts-has_passed) AS failed_attempts
FROM quizzes
GROUP BY quiz_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

Select quiz_id, (sum(attempts) - count(*)) as failed attempt from quizzes 
Group by quiz_id